# Calculating forward or backwards with pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate % differences in a dataframe by week, and put those calculations in a new dataframe.

Start with `df`:

```
index       Date     Zone      Amount
  0     2011-01-08  YQHDK   1691938000.0
  1     2011-02-05  YQHDK   1760009000.0
  2     2011-03-05  YQHDK   1893000000.0
```

New dataframe `newdf` would look like:

```
index       Date     Zone   % diff
  0     2011-02-05  YQHDK    4.02
  1     2011-03-05  YQHDK    7.56
```

How can I achieve this without going through a loop?

Comment: Is the ratio always taken between adjacent rows? (What does "by week" mean?)

Comment: Each row is associated with a different week, the % diff for index 1 would be (1691938000 - 1760009000) / 1691938000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
In [15]: df.Amount.pct_change()*100
Out[15]:
0         NaN
1    4.023256
2    7.556268
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

or

```
In [16]: df.Amount.pct_change().shift(-1)*100
Out[16]:
0    4.023256
1    7.556268
2         NaN
Name: Amount, dtype: float64

In [8]: df['pct_diff'] = df.Amount.pct_change()*100

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
   index        Date   Zone        Amount  pct_diff
0      0  2011-01-08  YQHDK  1.691938e+09       NaN
1      1  2011-02-05  YQHDK  1.760009e+09  4.023256
2      2  2011-03-05  YQHDK  1.893000e+09  7.556268
```

Comment: Could I do this with a df that had many Zone's using groupby?

Comment: @Lisle, can you update you question with an example or post a new question?